# Wii U - Can I have my own save game data?

Tags: wii-u, mario-kart-8

I want to play Mario Kart on Wii U, but I don't want to mess with the existing game data.  Is there a way I can have my own separate profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, just use a different Mii profile. Each Mii will have a different save file. Within your own Mii it is not possible to have multiple save games.

Comment: To clarify: not within the game itself, but in the upper-left of the WiiU main menu, you can tap to choose a different Mii-profile.